# Hbase number of regions keep growing

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

We are using hbase version 1.1.4. The DB has a around 40 tables, and each table data has a TimeToLive specified. It is deployed on a 5 node cluster, and the following is the hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>phoenix.query.threadPoolSize</name>
<value>2048</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
<value>21474836480</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.hregion.memstore.block.multiplier</name>
<value>4</value>
</property>
<!-- default is 64MB 67108864 -->
<property>
<name>hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size</name>
<value>536870912</value>
</property>
<!-- default is 7, should be at least 2x compactionThreshold -->
<property>
<name>hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles</name>
<value>240</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
<value>10000</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.bucketcache.ioengine</name>
<value>offheap</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.bucketcache.size</name>
<value>40960</value>
</property>
```

Question is that the number of regions on each of the regionservers keep growing. Currently we only merge regions using

```
merge_region in the hbase shell.
```

Is there any way to have only a fixed number of regions, on each server, or an automated way to merge the regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it mostly depends on your data: how is it distributed across keys. Assuming your values have almost same size for all keys, you can use partitioning:

For example, if your table key is `String` and you want 100 regions, use this

```
public static byte[] hashKey(String key) {
    int partition = Math.abs(key.hashCode() % 100);
    String prefix = partitionPrefix(partition);
    return Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes(prefix), ZERO_BYTE, key);
}

public static String partitionPrefix(int partition) {
    return StringUtils.leftPad(String.valueOf(partition), 2, '0');
}
```

In this case, all you keys will be prepended with numbers 00-99, so you have 100 partitions for 100 regions. Now you can disable region splits:

```
HTableDescriptor td = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("myTable"));
td.setRegionSplitPolicyClassName("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.DisabledRegionSplitPolicy");
```

or via shell

```
alter 'myTable', {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {METADATA => {'SPLIT_POLICY' => 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.DisabledRegionSplitPolicy'}}
```

Comment: I have disabled the splits now. What about the tables where it already has split regions?

Comment: @sparkDabbler if you decide to use partitioning, you have to transfer the data to new table and then replace them. if you only disabled splits, number of regions will stay the same but your regions will be disabalanced

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to have only a fixed number of regions, on each
>   server, or an automated way to merge the regions?

One way I have implemented this is create table with presplit regions. for example

```
create 'test_table', 'f1', SPLITS=> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

design good rowkey with will starts with 1-9

you can use guava murmur hash  like below.

```
import com.google.common.hash.HashCode;
import com.google.common.hash.HashFunction;
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

/**
     * getMurmurHash.
     * 
     * @param content
     * @return HashCode
     */
    public static HashCode getMurmurHash(String content) {
        final HashFunction hf = Hashing.murmur3_128();
        final HashCode hc = hf.newHasher().putString(content, Charsets.UTF_8).hash();
        return hc;
    }

final long hash = getMurmur128Hash(Bytes.toString(yourrowkey as string)).asLong();
            final int prefix = Math.abs((int) hash % 9);
```

now append this prefix to your rowkey

For example

1rowkey1 // will go in to first region
2rowkey2 // will go in to second region
3rowkey3 // will go in to third region
...
9rowkey9 // will go in to ninth region

If you are doing pre-splitting, and want to manually manage region splits, you can also disable region splits, by setting `hbase.hregion.max.filesize` to a high number and setting the split policy to `ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy`. However, you should use a safeguard value of like 100GB, so that regions does not grow beyond a region server’s capabilities. You can consider disabling automated splitting and rely on the initial set of regions from pre-splitting for example, if you are using uniform hashes for your key prefixes, and you can ensure that the read/write load to each region as well as its size is uniform across the regions in the table.

Also, look [at](http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/)

Comment: updated my answer with murmur 128 hash with guava api which ensures that uniformly distributed hashcode

Comment: I have disabled splits now, will have to wait for a day to see if the growth of regions stops.